# row-class not working in angular template

Tags: css, angular

I have this template that is working fine.

But when I want to separate the single-course (or product) in a component, `row`-class not working fine and items are under each other...

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="row">
        <app-single-course></app-single-course>
        <app-single-course></app-single-course>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

this is the code without single component and its working fine if I copy it they appear side by side.

```
            <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-course-inner style-two">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <img src="assets/img/course/2.png" alt="img">
                            <div class="rating">4.9/5 <i class="fa fa-star"></i></div>
                            <a href="#" class="bookmark"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="details">
                            <div class="meta">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>5,957 students</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 text-right">
                                        <p>01h 49m</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h5><a href="#">Motion Graphics: Create a Nice Typography Animation</a></h5>
                            <div class="price-inner">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>$33.99</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 text-right">
                                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where the row class is defined?

Comment: Its in vendor.css

Answer (score 0):

I think you might talk about the bootstrap grid system.
Well first of all the col class comes inside the row class or else you'll always have item "under each other".
Here is the documentation with examples : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/

Comment: can you share code for your answer. this is in case contents of shared link change or move elsewhere. best to have some code here in your answer on stackoverflow.